# Mapping D disk using cmd command

Tags: windows-command-prompt, mapping

I tried to map disk D with the next command in Command Prompt **"net use Y: \ComputerName\D$"** and I get errors.
Can you help me with the correct syntax?
But if I want to map a folder let's say Share from disk D.
When I map disk D from Explorer with Map Network Drive utility everythings is fine, but not when I am trying with cmd.

Comment: Try `net use Y: \\ComputerName\D$` (or `net use Y: \\%ComputerName%\D$`?)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
net use Y: \\ComputerName\D$
```

You were missing a Backslash " \ ". Maybe you want to add the additional parameter `/p` to map the network drive permanent.

> and I get errors

Which you sadly did no tell us.